# Grails not working getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am trying to run grails 2.1.1 version in windows 7 machine, in the command prompt if I provide grails command, I am getting **'Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandl
er in thread "main"'.** I tried to delete .grails, .groovy, .grails_history and .m2 files from user directory, but no luck. Also I set the environment variables 
GRAILS_HOME = C:\grails-2.1.0 
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07. Please help.

Note: this happens in eclipse too.

Comment: Have you copied  this over from a non-windows machine?  Have you cleaned the project?  Is the project shipping with some libs on its own?

Comment: Yes I tried to clean the project and run, but no luck. Even I could not able to create a new grails project.

Comment: There is an antivirus software in my windows machine, which is blocking grails to access. Now the issue resolved.